# FFC Connector Replacement

Tags: pcb, connector, display, ffc

I'm looking for an PCB FFC connector to replace the FH26-24S-0.3SHW(05), which I cannot find stocked anywhere. I've looked for replacements with .3mm pitch, .2mm flex thickness, and 24 contacts, but cannot find any via either DigiKey or Mouser. I can, however, find connectors with 25 pins. Would having one extra unused contact on the PCB FFC connector cause problems when using a 24-contact cable, assuming the cable was seated such that contacts 1-24 were aligned properly?

Comment: Is it some custom connector? Because Hirose doesn't have 24 pin listed for this part. https://www.hirose.com/product/series/FH26?lang=en# Are you sure the part exists? Because it isn't listed as valid in the datasheet.

Comment: The part number comes from the documentation for a Chinese LCD display I'm evaluating. It's possible that there is a mistake in the documentation. I will contact the company.

Comment: Chinese LCD datasheets aren't known for their amazing quality, but surely you know if the display has 24 or 25 pins. You'll be able to tell from the signal list pin-out if nothing else.

Comment: After contacting the company, they have recommended a new connector. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better try to find 24P connector from different manufacturer or different type.
It would be potential risk to use 25P. Yes, it will probably work. But imagine somebody will service that device (a year later) and will forget (or won't know at all) that there is 25P connector and 24P flat flex cable and will connect it misaligned. There could be some sort of short, which could fry your LCD.

I would use it ONLY as a temporary "solution".

Comment: No you can't show a 24P FFC into a 25P connector. These are extreme fine-pitch 0.3mm and therefore very picky with cable position. It is easy to get a bad connection even if you have the correct connector - you absolutely do need the mechanical plastic sides of the connector to guide the flex cable. So I wouldn't even begin to consider using a connector with wrong number of pins.